# How to program RS232 over Ethernet?

Tags: android, network-programming, serial-port, network-protocols

An existng system, with a server and terminals communicating over RS232.

Now the terminals are to be replaced with Android slate PCs and minimal changes should be made to the server.

I presume they will use RS232 to Ethernet convertors at the server, but how will the traffic look to the Android? Which protocol? How to I read and write an Ascii string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends entirely on the hardware you buy, but generally this is done over Telnet or similar.

While Telnet does have a *basic* protocol that sometimes gets followed for terminals, generally it is as connect on a specific port (such as 23) and send and receive data.  That data is then relayed to RS232.

Comment: Yeuck! but thanks for the answer (+1). Any pointers to how implement this?